# File sharing via OMEMO that also works when the other end is offline

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, file-sharing, omemo

I am working on a project in which I am implementing end to end encryption in XMPP protocol. I am using OMEMO extension of XMPP to achieve so. I am stuck at file sharing via OMEMO that should also work when the other end is offline.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OMEMO Media Sharing](https://xmpp.org/extensions/inbox/omemo-media-sharing.html), which should be exactly what you want. OMEMO media sharing is basically OMEMO encrypted HTTP file upload, which does also work when the recipient is offline.

Comment: Please give an example of the code and not just a link to a possible solution!

Comment: I don't have a link to code for xmppframework on iOS. You should be able to implement OMEMO media sharing given the XEP alone though.

Edit: And if you do implement it using xmppframework, consider upstreaming your code to contribute back to the project ;)